# Can someone explain me this recursive function?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand a recursive function.

here it is

```
let printAllCombinations = (arr, n, r) => {
  let data = new Array(r);
  arrayCalcuator(arr, data, 0, n - 1, 0, r);
};

// arr === array, data === tempArray, start === start Index, end ===  end Index, index == current index, r = size of combination
let arrayCalcuator = (array, data, start, end, index, r) => {
console.log("before calcualtor");
  if (index === r) {
    for (let j = 0; j < r; j++) {
    //   console.log('do something');
    }
  }

  for (let i = start; i <= end && end - i + 1 >= r - index; i++) {
    console.log(array, i, array[i]);
    data[index] = array[i];
    arrayCalcuator(array, data, i + 1, end, index + 1, r);
  }
   console.log("after calcualtor, exit the loop?");
};

printAllCombinations([5, 2, 3, 4], [5, 2, 3, 4].length, 3);
```

in the second for loop. I got the console like this. I am not understanding because in the code I clearly see that there is no code to decrease the `i` value. What am I missing here?

```
[ 5, 2, 3, 4 ] 0 5
[ 5, 2, 3, 4 ] 1 2
[ 5, 2, 3, 4 ] 2 3
[ 5, 2, 3, 4 ] 3 4
[ 5, 2, 3, 4 ] **3** 4


// how the number 3 goes to 2 I don't undershirt

[ 5, 2, 3, 4 ] **2** 3
[ 5, 2, 3, 4 ] 3 4
[ 5, 2, 3, 4 ] 1 2
[ 5, 2, 3, 4 ] 2 3
[ 5, 2, 3, 4 ] 3 4
```

Comment: Happens after exiting a recursive call. They're different instantiations of `i`. Put a `console.log` at the top and bottom of the `arrayCalculator` function so you can see function entry and exit.

Comment: @Ouroborus. As you mentioned I put 2 console.log before and after. I don't understand why the recursive function run again after reaching the end? It should exit the computation isn't that the correct way?

Comment: It doesn't run again. It returns, then the code which called `arrayCalcuator` picks up where it left off.You have a console.log just after a call to arrayCalcuator.

Comment: @Quentin. I am trying to see your point but I can't seem to understand. I will explain what I understand now.Normally the code goes from `top to bottom`. Because of the `recursive` the code goes from `bottom to start of the function again (arrayCalcuator )`. So if the code reach to the point when I `console.log('after calcualtor...')` that means that the condition is not met  for the `for` loop. and reach to another line. There is no recursive call after this. So from I understanding it should never reach to the top again.

Comment: "the code goes from bottom to start of the function again" — No. It calls the function again, and the new call to the function starts from the top. It doesn't move where it is in the current invocation of the function.

Comment: "So if the code reach to the point when I console.log('after calcualtor...') that means that the condition is not met for the for loop" — No - nothing *aborts* the previous run of the function. As I said, when `arrayCalcuator` returns the calling function (even if that calling function is also `arrayCalcuator`) picks up where it left off.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/sacoluqeke/1/edit?js,console — `two` finished and `one` picks up where it left off. Calling another function (even if it is the same function) doesn't prevent the code from reaching `console.log("end of one")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, look at the loop condition:

```
i <= end && end - i + 1 >= r - index
```

`i` is `start`, so it goes from `start` to `end`. The second condition basically just does an adjusted `end + 1 >= r`.

Now, on the recursive call:

```
arrayCalcuator(array, data, i + 1, end, index + 1, r);
```

`i + 1` is `start` and `index + 1` is the `index` parameters, respectively. So that just starts another loop with `i` using "starting" at +1.

So...

- First call, starts a loop on 0, which triggers the second call.
- Second call, starts another loop on 1, which triggers the third call.
- Third call, starts another loop on 2, which triggers the fourth call.
- Fourth call, starts another loop on 3, which triggers the fifth call.
- Fifth call, does not loop since `4` is bigger than the end, so no recursive call is done.
- Back to the fourth call, continues the loop with `i = 4` which fails for the same reason, so loop ends.
- Back to the third call, continues the loop with `i = 3` which starts a whole new stack of calls which will also fail to loop on the next call because `i` would be bigger than `end` (e.g. `4` again). It continues the loop once more and it exits for the same reasons.
- Back to the second call, continues the loop with `i = 2`, starts a new call stack which this time will loop.
- 2nd third call, continues the loop with `i = 3`.

And I think I already made the point here of why your log goes up and then down and then up.

If I were to print the stack:

```
 0
   1
    2
     3
    3
   2
     3
  1
    2
     3
```